# How to prevent cross site request forgery in MVC using c# web api as server and angular 5 as client side

Tags: c#, angular5

I am unable implement the Cross site request forgery functionality in
MVC using angular 5.

Comment: Welcome, please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry,I have searched but i could not get any solution so i didn't implement anything. All the solutions are in angular JS or ASP.NET mvc. I could n't the found the solution which i want.Could you please help me in this to resolve.

Comment: Angular confusingly calls this XSRF (rather than the common CSRF) but it is built-in: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientXsrfModule - and once you know that, you can search for "XSRF Angular MVC" and find examples like [this](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1092572/xsrf-with-web-api-and-angular)

Comment: Hi stuard,By visiting your answer, i could not understand where to implement that . AS i am new to angular please can you tell briefly.

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't use Angular. I'm not a front-end dev at all, at least not any more. But didn't the CodeProject link help? It seemed quite comprehensive and well-written.

Answer (score 0):

I hope in c# we can handle using `EnableCorsAttribute`.[EnableCors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Comment: CORS doesn't stop CSRF. If evilsite.com makes a request to yoursite.com from the client browser, the origin is the same..

Comment: yes,CORS doesn't support CSRF. what stuartd said is correct.hi stuard can you please provide me the solution for this.